# How do I translate "Actualmente estoy cursando tercer año"?

Tags: translation, spanish

I am writing my resume and would like to say that I didn't finished my studies yet. So I would like to say which year is my current (I don't know if this phrase is even right).

In Spanish I would say "Actualmente estoy cursando el tercer año de mi carrera".

How would I say it in English?

I did some research and found that some would say "I am currently studying third year" but I think that it does not sound good because of the verb "studying"..

Comment: "I am in my third year of study."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this site is not a translation service.

Comment: @curiousdannii then why does the tag `translation` exist?

Comment: I don't know, but it's existence doesn't justify the question sorry. You could turn this into a phrase request question but you'd have to explain the full meaning with all its implications and connotations for us.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few possibilities for the sentence you gave: 
"At this time, I'm in my third year of school" 
"This is my third year of study"
"I'm currently in my third year of school"

Depending on what sort of study you are doing and what region you are in, you could also use other terms such as: "I'm a junior in college", whuch (in my region) means 'I am a third-year student in a four-year university program'.

Comment: "Actually" would be a mistranslation of "actualmente" if the meaning is "at the present time."

Comment: Oop, my bad. I'll fix that.

Answer (score 1):

Other suggestion

i.e.

```
Bachelor degree of Computer Science Engineer in progress, studying 6th semester.
```

Answer (score 0):

'.. currently am studying third year' is a literal and grammatical translation; however, 'didn't finished' is bad grammar.  This should be 'didn't finish' or 'haven't finished'.